# Problems with pictures on heroku

Tags: mysql, wordpress, image, heroku

I want to install my WordPress project on Heroku, but when I uploaded it to the server, I had problems with pictures. The server reboots every day and loses touch with the images, white spots appear in the gallery in place of them, and they simply disappear in the frontend.
I use the following rates:
[image]

Comment: Where are you storing the pictures? If they're just on-disk in the dyno, they won't be persistent between restarts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Tell me please how to solve, WordPress saves everything to disk in the upload folder

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://help.heroku.com/58GWW5CQ/can-i-use-wordpress-on-heroku?